# Error when trying to Fine Tune T5: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, t5-transformer

Been trying to Fine-Tune a T5 model on a certain dataset but even when following the step-by-step guide provided by Huggingface or using my own Trainer Class, the code was not running and always returning the same error when calling the `trainer.train()` seemingly when calculating the loss function.

this is my code based on the step by step guide found on the hugging face hub [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/translation)

So far this is my code:
`transformers.logging.set_verbosity_error()`

```
from datasets import load_dataset

canard_train_augm = load_dataset("gaussalgo/Canard_Wiki-augmented", split="train")
canard_test_augm = load_dataset("gaussalgo/Canard_Wiki-augmented", split="test")
```

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_name = "t5-small"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
    combined_input = examples["Question"] + ": " + examples["true_contexts"]
    return tokenizer(combined_input, examples["Rewrite"],max_length=512, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
```

```
tokenized_train = canard_train_augm.map(preprocess_function)
tokenized_test = canard_test_augm.map(preprocess_function)
```

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model_name)
```

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model_name)
```

```
import evaluate

metric = evaluate.load("sacrebleu")
```

```
import numpy as np


def postprocess_text(preds, labels):
    preds = [pred.strip() for pred in preds]
    labels = [[label.strip()] for label in labels]

    return preds, labels

def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)

    result = metric.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels)
    result = {"bleu": result["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds]
    result["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    result = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result
```

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="wtf",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_total_limit=3,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    fp16=True,
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_train,
    eval_dataset=tokenized_test,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

I tried several examples including my own Customized Class for the trainer function but always ended with the same issue even when I tried the same code found in the step-by-step guide provided by huggingface.

The error happens when calling the `trainer.train()` returning the following:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I followed the exact same format as the documentation and I believe it is something that is happening when calling the loss function but was just unable to put my finger to it, if anyone can help that would be great.